# mysql procedure if condition

Tags: mysql, if-statement, operators, procedure

I have a mysql procedure that it doesn´t work an IF condition with AND. I'm not sure what is the correct syntax.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE insere_orcamento(
 IN ida VARCHAR(10),
 IN volta VARCHAR(10),
 OUT result INT
)
BEGIN

 IF (ida='sim' AND volta=NULL) THEN
    SET result = 50;
 ELSEIF (ida=NULL AND volta='sim') THEN
    SET result = 51;
 END IF;

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value NULL must be checked with IS

Or like **akina** said you can also use  <=>

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insere_orcamento`(
 IN ida VARCHAR(10),
 IN volta VARCHAR(10),
 OUT result INT
)
BEGIN

 IF (ida='sim' AND volta IS NULL) THEN
    SET result := 50;
 ELSEIF (ida IS NULL AND volta = 'sim') THEN
    SET result := 51;
 END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: *The value NULL must be checked with IS* .. or using `<=>`.